# How to open Java Library System files in eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, libraries

I'm getting excited at the moment to open `Java library files` that what contains in it, i mean which type of coding oracle nowadays using, I know that to make an API is easy step, but want to know how to open these library files, as simply i do click, this shows an error:

please see this in [pic](http://postimg.org/image/69n3le8ql/)

Help Would be appreciated!. thanks

Comment: OpenJDK is (as the name implies) open source, so you're best off just cloning their repo to take a peek around. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u40

Comment: Are you going to decompile them?

Comment: @SuperHornet: Just want to look into their resources(library files) that what contains in it..

Answer (score 1):

You can attach source code of Java in your IDE.
In Eclipse go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Then select jre6/jre7(whatever is there in your system) and click Edit.
Then You can see "Source Attachment" on right hand side, click on that.

Then you can attach src.zip file that is provided by Oracle in your installation directory of java(Ex : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\src.zip).

After that click Ok and there you go. You can see any Java Library Class Files like String.class or Thread.class etc.